# Nuget List-Package Error

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I tried to execute "List-Package" in Package manager console and getting following error in Nuget package.

```
The term 'List-Package' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
 verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:13
+ List-Package <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (List-Package:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

i typed  get-help Nuget to see all available Nuget commands.But i could not see "List-Package" in the result.

Is this error happening because  `List-Package` command no longer supported in latest version of  Nuget? May be we need to use command `Get-package list-package` instead of `List-Package`

what is causing this error?

Answer (score 4):

`List-Package` is incorrect command name.

You should use `Get-Package` command

[Look details at docs.nuget.org](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console)